# Enthalpy vs. energy change in a gas reaction with fewer moles of gas produced

Tags: thermodynamics

> If $\Delta H$ is the change in enthalpy, $\Delta U$ the change in internal energy accompanying a gaseous reaction, then $\Delta H < \Delta U$, only if the number of moles of products is less than the number of moles of reactants.

Could you explain the above statement? Moreover, I have read that enthalpy and internal energy are extensive properties. How will they be affected because of the change in the number of moles?

I believe the changes are related according to
$$
\Delta H = \Delta U + P\Delta V.
$$

Answer (score 1):

If a chemical reaction occurs in a closed system at constant temperature (i.e., the initial and final temperatures are the same), then, from the ideal gas law, $$\Delta (PV)=RT\Delta n $$So, $$\Delta H=\Delta U+RT\Delta n$$